# How do I disable the Mobile Hotspot feature?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

As far as I can remember, some carriers disable this feature. Now, we have a few dozen phones that we want to deploy to some schools and we would like to disable this feature.

How do I achieve this? A few guesses that I have would be to add/edit something in `build.prop` or some hidden Android API (can't find any [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html)).

---

**Update:** I figured it out a long time ago. The solutions here do work gracefully and the phones behave properly. Normal WiFi is not affected (because `hostapd` only manages the AP). Upon testing, the worst that happens is

```
2018-12-04 23:12:23.680 3207-3753/? E/SoftapController: Unable to open connection to supplicant on "/data/misc/wifi/hostapd/wlan0": No such file or directory
```

in the `logcat`.  At the same time, the mobile hotspot setting switch flips back off automagically.

What I did was just rename `hostapd` to something else. Moving/deleting/changing permissions would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to add that you can alternatively remove the execution permission from that file:

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
chmod 0644 /system/bin/hostapd
```

This approach looks more Unix-styled.

To restore it, do the same commands again, but use `0755` instead of `0644` (i.e. put the execute permission back).

Answer (score 6):

I managed to solve this without deleting hostapd file (with this method you can easily reactivate hotspot functionality renaming hostapd back to its original name).

1. Root your phone
2. Open up adb connection
3. Enter these commands:

   ```
   su
   cd system
   cd bin
   mount -o rw,remount /system
   mv hostapd inactive_hostapd
   mount -o ro,remount /system
   ```
4. Reboot your phone and you're ready to go.

If you want hotspot functionality back to your phone, just rename it back to 'hostapd' (`mv inactive_hostapd hostapd`).

Tested on Motorola Moto C Plus.

Comment: hostapd doesn't seems to exists anymore on Android 11.  How could the wifi hotspot feature removed in this android version?

Answer (score 3):

Erase this file (with root): `system/bin/hostapd`

Answer (score 0):

Without rooting phone:

Install a display overlay app like "AppLock" and block access to "Settings".

Comment: You'd need to also block the drop down access to it.  Which would suck from a user experience standpoint.

Comment: you wouldn't be able to access the settings to set the hotspot name and password though, provided you cleared those in the first place of course.