# I'm trying to disable hotspot but I can't find hostapd on android 9

Tags: adb, root-access

I'm trying to permanently disable hotspot on my phone. I saw this answer here
[How do I disable the Mobile Hotspot feature?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/how-do-i-disable-the-mobile-hotspot-feature?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I've connected my phone (ulefone armor 6e) to adb  but I can't find hostapd in system/bin/ does anyone know where it is in Android 9? ( I can find it easily in an android 7 phone)
   or another file to delete that will do job without damaging anything else? 
I've not yet rooted my phone and I know I will have to try to do this to delete system files.  But i would like to at least find the file i need to delete first.

Or is there an easier way?:D

Comment: In `/vendor/bin/`. Or `/odm/bin/`. Since Android 8 hardware-specific vendor code is isolated from generic AOSP code in separate partition(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   It doesn't seem to be in vendor/bin.  I when i change directory to odm it lists bin as being there but when I type 'cd bin' I get  '/system/bin/sh: cd:  /odm/bin: No such file or directory'

Comment: It can be in some subdirectory e.g. `/vendor/bin/hw/hostapd`. You can run `adb shell find /system /vendor /odm /product -name hostapd 2>/dev/null`. Or `adb shell grep -I hostapd /*/etc/init/*.rc`. Or `adb shell ps -A -o cmdline | grep hostapd`. And so on. If you still cannot find the binary then SELinux might not be allowing `adb` to access vendor stuff. But `hostapd` is definitely there. Just root your phone and you'll have access to everything. And sorry but your query is about basic usage of shell, not Android.