# How to run device into repeater mode with shell script?

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, shell, android-11, wifi-direct

Currently my device on LineageOS 18.1 (Android 11) with root access and supported managed mode and AP mode at the same time.

```
root@localhost:~# uname -a
Linux localhost 4.9.326-Mi8937 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Sep 12 02:37:27 UTC 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

root@localhost:~# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_CFG80211
CONFIG_CFG80211=y
# CONFIG_CFG80211_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS is not set
# CONFIG_CFG80211_CERTIFICATION_ONUS is not set
CONFIG_CFG80211_DEFAULT_PS=y
# CONFIG_CFG80211_DEBUGFS is not set
CONFIG_CFG80211_INTERNAL_REGDB=y
# CONFIG_CFG80211_CRDA_SUPPORT is not set
# CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT is not set

root@localhost:~# lshw | grep wireless=
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wcnss_wlan multicast=yes wireless=Qcom:802.11n

root@localhost:~# iw phy | grep -iA2 'valid interface combinations'
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 3, #{ IBSS, AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 3, #channels <= 2
```

I did search over internet and found this [WI-FI REPEATER MODE ON ANDROID by Irfan Latif](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202335) and this [android_wifi_repeater by mrbox24](https://github.com/mrbox24/android_wifi_repeater) but seems those script doesn't support android 11 because when I check `/system/bin` and `/system/xbin`, no `hostapd` there.

> *My goal is to be able to run my device into repeater mode using wifi-direct that can be run with shell script command and no need to set Client Wifi proxy port.*

Thanks.

**Edit (Sept 28, 2022)**
Referring to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221231#comment286327_221231),
I found that `hostapd` exist under `/vendor/bin/hw` path. Thanks Irfan.

And now I got another problem, I can run the [mnet script](https://github.com/mrbox24/android_wifi_repeater), Client able to connect to the Host but without Internet Connection.

Tried `ping 192.168.49.1` from Client to Host device got `100% loss`, but works when `ping` from Host device to Client device.

Comment: "*when I check `/system/bin` and `/system/xbin`, no `hostapd` there*". See [this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221231#comment286327_221231).

Comment: @IrfanLatif, you're right. I found that under ```/vendor/bin/hw``` path.

Comment: @IrfanLatif,  Now I got another problem, the script run and I can connected client device to the host device but without internet access. From client device, `ping 192.168.49.1` (host IP) it doesn't work / ping 100% loss. But when `ping` from host to client device, it works. How to fix that problem? Thanks.