# How do I disable the Mobile Hotspot feature? Android 14

Tags: wi-fi, networking, hardware, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I am trying to disable hotspot on One plus nord (Lineage OS 21) Android 14

[This is the original question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/how-do-i-disable-the-mobile-hotspot-feature) but the hostapd file has been moved to `/vendor/bin/hw`

```
Nord:/vendor/bin/hw # find /system /vendor /odm /product -name hostapd 2>/dev/null

/vendor/bin/hw/hostapd
```

But when i try to use the original solution this is what i get

```
Nord:/vendor/bin/hw # mount -o rw,remount /vendor
Nord:/vendor/bin/hw # chmod 0644 hostapd
chmod: chmod 'hostapd' to 0644: Read-only file system
```

I am running the shell as root denoted by the # in the shell